# How many solutions are there?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The problem from some math competition (multiple-choice test):

Consider an equation $\lfloor\sqrt{12}x\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{7}{2}x\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes integer part of $x$ (entier). This equation:

A. has exactly 1 real solution

B. for $x>150$ has at least 1 integer solution

C. has exactly 28 integer solutions

D. has at least 7 natural solutions

My try:

I found out that there are 15 integer solutions:

-14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13

So I answered "D".
However it turned out that it is not correct. I have no idea why. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you saying that your solutions are the only ones?

Comment: Hi did you try to solve it?

Comment: Igor - I claim that they are the only integer solutions.

Comment: Well, I tried several integers values - I noticed that for $x>13 \vee x<-14$ the difference between $\sqrt{12}x$ and $\frac{7}{2}x$ is too large.

Comment: D **is** correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But it is possible that C is correct also (so it could be preferred, because it is more precise -- yes I agree that would be dumb...)

Comment: `for(var x=-100;x<=100;x++) if(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(12)*x) == Math.floor(7/2*x)) console.log(x);` There are 28 solutions between -26 to 13.

Comment: D is correct.  C is also correct.

Comment: Bad question, unless the instructions allow marking more than one choice. Neither (C) nor (D) implies the other, so hypothetical instructions to choose the strongest true answer wouldn’t help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 28 integer solutions: -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13

Answer (score 2):

To supplement JiminP, one way you to start this is to place bounds on $x$ is to check when it's absolutely false:

$$\begin{align} \left|\frac72x-\sqrt{12}x\right|&\ge 1\\
x^2\left(\frac72-\sqrt{12}\right)^2&\ge1\\
x^2\left(\frac{97}4-7\sqrt{12}\right)&\ge 1\\
x^2&\ge\frac{1}{\frac{97}{4}-7\sqrt{12}}\\
x^2&\ge\frac{1\left(\frac{97}4+7\sqrt{12}\right)}{\frac1{16}}\\
|x|&\ge4\sqrt{\frac{97}4+7\sqrt{12}} \end{align}$$
With one or two upward approximations (in particular, $\sqrt{12}\to \frac72$ and $\sqrt{195}\to 14$), we get $|x|\ge 28$.  Obviously that's a pretty weak bound but it gives you a range to check (i.e. $-28<x<28$), instead of just dealing with infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty clear. There are at least $7$ integer solutions, hence $(D)$. If it is wrong, then it was not $\sqrt{12}$ but something else. Indeed, the first question had $\sqrt{2}$ instead.

Comment: $\sqrt{12}$ makes heuristic sense because $\sqrt{12}=\frac{\sqrt{48}}{2}\approx \frac72$.  OP was the one that corrected it from $\sqrt 2$ anyway.

Comment: It seems that both C and D are correct. How can D not be correct ?